# When to add a scalar to a named query

Tags: hibernate

When is it necessary to add a scalar to a named query?e.g:

```
<return-scalar column="colName" type="java.lang.String" />
```

Sometimes they seem to be not needed, while sometimes, without the scalar, the query will throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

Let me share some inputs.

1. If your query is *select * from table* setScalar can be used to dynamically limit the no of columns.
2. If you use scalar the query will not use  **ResultSetMetadata** to find the type and will use the type provided which is faster and effective.
3. How the java.sql.Types returned from ResultSetMetaData is mapped to Hibernate types is controlled by the Dialect. If a specific type is not mapped, or does not result in the expected type, it is possible to customize it via calls to registerHibernateType in the Dialect.

Read the documentation for more details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13646)